# How to cast int to float in GLSL (WebGL)?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

My code is (inside the void main):

```
float res;

for(int i=0; i<15; i++) {

    res = float(i)/15.0;

    //...

}
```

Unfortunately I get a syntax error at `float(i)/15.0`

If I just write `i/15.0`, then the error is:

```
wrong operand types  no operation '/' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'mediump int' and a right operand of type 'const float' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

If I just try `i/15` then the result is an integer, but I would like to get a float.

How is it possible to cast `int` to `float`?

Comment: In javascript this conversion is done automatically - res = i / 15;

Comment: This is GLSL, not javascript

Comment: I [pasted your code above into glslsandbox.com and it works just fine](http://glslsandbox.com/e#28445.0). Are you sure you didn't get that error from a different line in your shader?

Comment: "I get a syntax error at float(i)/15.0" Are you sure? This seems fine, float(i) is the correct way to convert i to float.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[It seems](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/583390-glsl-problem-integer-and-float-comparison/?view=findpost&p=4711507) that you're not allowed to cast in GLSL. Therefore, *"you have to use [a constructor](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Constructors)"*.

Try this:

```
// http://www.shaderific.com/glsl-types/
// "Implicit type conversions are not supported.
// Type conversions can be done using constructors..."
float i_float = float(i);
res = i_float / 15.0;
```

<strike>PS: If you have a look [at the documentation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Implicit_conversion), it says that *"... Either integer type can be converted into floats, and integers and floats can be converted into doubles."* ... I find it odd that your code is not accepted by the GLSL compiler.</strike> (cf. Reto Koradi's comment)

Comment: You're looking at documentation for full GLSL. The GLSL version used with WebGL is based on GLSL ES 1.00 (the GLSL version that goes along with OpenGL ES 2.0), which does not support implicit type conversions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added a new reference: http://www.shaderific.com/glsl-types/

Comment: I still get syntax error for some reason: `An error occurred compiling the shaders: ERROR: 0:33: '1.0' : syntax error`

Comment: Could you please post the whole shader code so we can have a more concrete view on the problem ?